# How do I escape an equals character in a AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments property passed to sqlpackage.exe?

Tags: escaping, sqlpackage

[`sqlpackage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) is a command in SQL Server used with [DACPACs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications).  It can take an argument of the form `/p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments=...` where `...` is a semi-colon delimited list of key-value like this `key1=value1;key2=value2`.  I would like to pass a value containing `=` but when I specify this as:

```
sqlpackage /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="key1=prefix = suffix;key2=...;key3=..."
```

`sqlpackage` misinterprets and I end up passing only `key2` and `key3`.  I have tried using `%3D`, `\=`, `\\=`, `\\\=` and `\\\\=` but none of them worked.